# R calculate how many values used to calculate mean in aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe of daily observations dating from 1963-2022. I want to calculate the mean of the observation for each month. However, some months don't have data for each day and some only have one datapoint for one month. This skews some of the data points. How do I calculate how many observations have been used to calculate the mean for a given month.

#### Head of Data frame

```
   structure(list(prcp_amt = c(0, 1.8, 6.4, 5.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 
4.8, 0, 0, 4.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 3.6, 6.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ob_date = structure(c(-220838400, -220752000, 
-220665600, -220579200, -220492800, -220406400, -220320000, -220233600, 
-220147200, -220060800, -219974400, -219888000, -219801600, -219715200, 
-219628800, -219542400, -219456000, -219369600, -219283200, -219196800, 
-219110400, -219024000, -218937600, -218851200, -218764800, -218678400, 
-218592000, -218505600, -218419200, -218332800, -218246400, -218160000, 
-218073600, -217987200, -217900800, -217814400, -217728000, -217641600, 
-217555200, -217468800, -217382400, -217296000, -217209600, -217123200, 
-217036800, -216950400, -216864000, -216777600, -216691200, -216604800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Existing code

```
# historic monthly rainfall
rainHist$month <- as.numeric(format(rainHist$ob_date, '%m'))
rainHist$year <- as.numeric(format(rainHist$ob_date, '%Y'))
rainHistMean <- aggregate(prcp_amt ~ month + year, rainHist, FUN=mean)
rainHistMean$day <- 01

rainHistMean <-
  rainHistMean %>%
    mutate(rainHistMean, Date=paste(year, month, day, sep='-'))

rainHistMean[['Date']] <- as.POSIXct(rainHistMean[['Date']],
                                     format='%Y-%m-%d',
                                     tz='GMT'
                                     )
```

#### Updated Code

```
rainHist$month <- as.numeric(format(rainHist$ob_date, '%m'))
rainHist$year <- as.numeric(format(rainHist$ob_date, '%Y'))
rainHistMean <- aggregate(prcp_amt ~ month + year, rainHist, FUN=function(x) c(mean(x), length(x)))
names(rainHistMean) <- c('month', 'year', 'prcp_amt', 'n')
```

How do I get there to be 4 columns not 3 with a matrix?

[image]

#### Solution

```
rainHist$month <- as.numeric(format(rainHist$ob_date, '%m'))
rainHist$year <- as.numeric(format(rainHist$ob_date, '%Y'))
rainHistMean <- aggregate(prcp_amt ~ month + year, rainHist, FUN=function(x) c(mean(x), length(x)))
rainHistMean <- data.frame(rainHistMean[1:2], rainHistMean[[3]])
names(rainHistMean) <- c('month', 'year', 'prcp_amt', 'n')
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi How do you get a column of both mean and length?

Comment: Where in the code do I put that? As part of the aggregate() function?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi could you see my update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant solutions, but you can use `dplyr` to group by month and year, then get the count and mean in `summarize`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(month(ob_date), year(ob_date)) %>% 
  summarize(mean_prcp = mean(prcp_amt),
            count = n())
```

Output:

```
# # Groups:   month(ob_date) [2]
# `month(ob_date)` `year(ob_date)` mean_prcp count
# <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
# 1                1            1963      0.91    30
# 2                2            1963      0.77    20
```